# load a class without knowing name in a specific folder in java

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I have a java app that do some operation in a file and release output of results. and I want add a property that everyone that use my app can add his/her specific operator. and know i want to load class without knowing its name or methods.

this is my class and i know the class and method name that might be added:

```cs
public class PathGetter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        String AbsolutePath = args[0];
        AbsolutePath += "\\in.txt";

        String SecondFilePath = args[1];
        SecondFilePath += "\\out.txt";

        File file = new File(SecondFilePath);
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        FileReader fr = new FileReader();
        Object newOp = null;
        String newOpSign="!@#$%^&*";
        Method m = null;

        MathOperations mathOperations = new MathOperationsImpl();

        System.out.println("Do you have new operator? ");
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in); 

        if(scanner1.nextBoolean()==true){
            Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter operator sign: ");
            newOpSign = scanner2.nextLine();

            File addedClass= new File("E:\\workspace\\940420\\bin");

            URI uri = addedClass.toURI();
            URL[] urls = new URL[]{uri.toURL()};

            ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);

            Class clazz = classLoader.loadClass("second.MathOperationsUpdateImpl");   \\I don't know the class name might be added

            newOp = clazz.newInstance();    
            m = newOp.getClass().getMethod("mathOperate", String.class); \\I don't know the method name in added class

        }



        ArrayList<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < fr.readFile(AbsolutePath).size(); i++) {
            if((fr.readFile(AbsolutePath).get(i)).contains(newOpSign)){

                answer.add(i,  String.valueOf(m.invoke(newOp,(fr.readFile(AbsolutePath).get(i)))));
            }
            else{
                answer.add(i, String.valueOf(mathOperations.mathOperate(fr.readFile(AbsolutePath).get(i))));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < fr.readFile(AbsolutePath).size(); i++) {
            writer.write(answer.get(i)+ "\r\n");
        }

        writer.close();

        System.out.print("Your File Successfully Created In: " + SecondFilePath);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: I cannot follow. What is your concrete question? If you don't know the class and/or method name, using reflection is the right way (but you use reflection already).

Comment: It is just the code I wrote it for myself, I want to change the code so can make object from a class that user wrote it in a specific path that i know! but i don't know qualification class name and its methods. i want to make an instance of a class that might be added by user of my code. (I just know the path of user's class)

Comment: So you know the name and path of the class file. Load it with `Class c = Class.forName(<classname")`. Than you can get all available methods via reflection, too: `Methods[] m = c.getMethods()`. You can get more information about the methods via `m[0].getName()` for example.

Comment: If you don't know the class name, you can use `File` to get the content of the directory: `File d = new File(<knowDirectroy>); File[] f = d.listFiles();`. Of course, there should be only one `.class` file in the directory. Otherwise, you have no change to load the correct class (or do you have any more information?)

Comment: Is any way to find our intended method in `m`? 
because we don't know about the class and methods that might be written, is any mechanism to find which method is is our required method?
we just know there is one method in a extended class that get a string as a parameter and return a Double type of result !

Comment: You can use `m.getParameterTypes()` and `m.getReturnType()` to look for a method with the designated signature. If there are multiple, there is no way to distinguish them (-> throw an exception or some other error handling). If there is only a single method with the signature just use it (call by reflection). Something like this:
`Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
Class<?> r = m.getReturnType();
if(params.length == 1 && params[0].getName().equals(String.class.getName())
&& r.getName().equals(Double.class.getName())) {
 /* invoke */
}`

Comment: If I force others to extend one of my abstract classes to define their operators, when i load their class **how can I set a superclass reference to loadedclass?** I think it is good way to hold method name. but I cant make reference to that loaded class!
something like `SuperClass superClass = loadedClass.newInstance();`
(loadedClass is subclass of SuperClass.)

Comment: You are on the right path. You only need to cast: use your abstract class as variable type and assign the loaded class to it. `Class childClass = Class.forName("DerivedClassName"); MyAbstractClass userOperator = (MyAbstractClass)childClass.newInstance();`

Comment: Thank you Matthias, you helped me a lot. I have just 2 week experience in programming. I wont forget your helps.

Comment: YW. However, I would suggest that you work through a text book to pick up the basics. (I cannot recommend any, however.)

Comment: I'm so sorry Matthias, could you take a look to my new problem please. I think u can help me more than others. 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510686/load-all-classes-in-a-specific-folder-without-knowing-package-name-java)

Comment: I just summarized my answer below. Mark it as an useful answer if you like. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summery of the comments to give final answer:

**1:** If you don't know the class name, you can use File to get the content of the directory:

```
File d = new File("<knowDirectory>");
File[] f = d.listFiles();
```

Of course, there should be only one `.class` file in the directory.

**2.:** So you know the name and path of the class file. Load it with

```
Class c = Class.forName("<classname>").
```

Than you can get all available methods via reflection, too:

```
Methods[] m = c.getMethods();
```

**3(A).:** If you don't know the name of the method you want to invoke, but its signature (ie, return type and parameters), you can use `m.getReturnType()` and `m.getParameterTypes()` to look for a method with the designated signature. If there are multiple, there is no way to distinguish them. If there is only a single method with the signature just use it (call by reflection). Something like this (for return type `Double` and single parameter `String`):

```
Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
Class<?> r = m.getReturnType();
if(r.getName().equals(Double.class.getName())
   && params.length == 1
   && params[0].getName().equals(String.class.getName()))
{
   // invoke
}
```

**3(B).:** If you force the user to implement an abstract class (or interface), hence, you know the name of the method to be implemented, load the class and cast it to the interface:

```
Class childClass = Class.forName("DerivedClassName");
MyAbstractClass userOperator = (MyAbstractClass)childClass.newInstance();
```