# Load all classes in a specific folder without knowing package name - java

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I have a code that load all classes in folder with same package name ( `second` ).

how can i change it to load all classes in a folder with deference package (not in `second`) (and we don't know the package name)

```
int classCounter = 0;

File folderAdded = new File("..//940424//second");
File [] classFileAdded = folderAdded.listFiles();
String [] addedClassName = new String [classFileAdded.length];
List<Operations> newOp = new ArrayList<Operations>();
Operations newOpTemp = null;

for(int i = 0; classCounter < classFileAdded.length; classCounter++){
    addedClassName [classCounter] = classFileAdded[classCounter].getAbsolutePath().substring(classFileAdded[classCounter].getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("\\")+1); 
    addedClassName [classCounter] = addedClassName[classCounter].substring(0,(addedClassName[classCounter].lastIndexOf(".")));
    addedClassName [classCounter] = "second." + addedClassName[classCounter];

    Class addedClass = Class.forName(addedClassName[classCounter]);
    newOpTemp = (Operations)addedClass.newInstance();
        if (newOpTemp instanceof Operations){
            newOp.add( i, newOpTemp);
            i++;
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to know the package and just give parent folder and then you can iterate over the folders recursively and filter all the files with the file name containing java. So you will get all the files

Comment: I tried it, when we have some classes in different packages (not `second`), in run time an exception occured ( `NoClassDefFoundError: second/ClassInThirdPackage(wrong name: third/ClassInThirdPackage)` ) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that come to my mind:

1. If you want to load classes, the corresponding folder must be in your classpath (can you ensure this -- as you don't know the folder's name?)
2. If you want to load a class with package `a.b.ClassName` the file must be located in folder `a/b/ClassName.class` (otherwise, loading will fail)

**update**

If you know the folder name, you also know the package name (that's the trick). It must correspond to each other in Java. If a class is in package `a.b` it *must* be in folder `a/b/`. If you only know the root-folder, ie, `pathToRootFolder/a/b/` you can search for folders using

```
File root = new File("<rootFolder>");
File[] files = root.listFiles()
```

and check each file if it is a directory:

```
for(File f : files) {
  if(f.isDirectory()) {
    // do processing
  }
}
```

If there is only one file in a single package structure, there should be only one directory and the name *must* corresponds to the package name (of course you need to "step into the directory" until there is no further nesting, ie, no sub-folder, and this last folder contains the actual class you want to load. This way to can extract the directory structure and thus the package name.

**end update**

Some side remarks about your code:

1. Why `//` in `new File("..//940424//second")` (is this a typo and should be `\\`) [btw: it is better to use `File.separator`]
2. Why do you have variable `i` in your for-loop but actually use `classCounter` ??
3. In `addedClassName[classCounter] = classFileAdded[classCounter].getAbsolutePath().substring(classFileAdded[classCounter].getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("\\")+1);` you extract the file name, right? Why you not just use `addedClassName[classCounter] = classFileAdded[classCounter].getName()`?

Comment: Problem is not folder name! We know folder name, but we don't know package name! User of this code might write his classes in a different package and put them in a folder that i said its path to him! I want to know is there any way to load classes independent of its package name?

about remarks: first thank you for your advises, No.1 and  No.3 you said right. thank you. No.2 I decided to check if the class that loaded is instance of my interface or not. if yes I needed to hold them otherwise no need to hold them.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("mysh.im.monitor");
reflections.getSubTypesOf(Monitor.class);
```

before that, make sure your folder is in your classpath.

maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```